# complete example of gettext in php

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

i've been googling for the last hour or so trying to find a complete working example of gettext in php - all source files, po files, with proper paths, etc. Just a "hello world" with all the required files.

I was wondering if anybody has such a working example. thanks in advance.

Comment: My personal, subjective opinion is that PHP's gettext functions suck *ass*. [Zend_Translate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) is much better and [supports gettext files](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html) as well

Comment: There are plenty of guides online talking about how to write PHP code that uses gettext, but a lot of them are missing set-up information (e.g. installing the right locales on your Linux machines, setting up gettext on Window, etc.).

If you've got the PHP code ready, but gettext still doesn't work, I've compiled a list of issues (and solutions) in an article while setting up gettext: https://blog.terresquall.com/2020/09/troubleshooting-php-gettext/

Answer (score 4):

I've read these other guides posted for this question, but none of them was complete enough for me and also they seem to be rushing into the subject.

**[THIS GUIDE](http://www.sitepoint.com/localizing-php-applications-1)** is divided in many parts, you'll learn from a simple `Hello World` to a complex plural management. It not just explain what every function does, but also the values used for these functions.

As a bonus, this guide teaches how to use [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) which is a very helpful toll for working with `gettext` internationalization and a must have if you are dealing with a huge project.

The OP may change the accepted answer to this one if he also think that guide is better. So this answer can get more attention and more `gettext` beginners like me can be helped.

Comment: When you add a new locale to a server (for testing use sudo locale-gen xx_XX) ensure that you restart the WWW server, otherwise you'll get errors. Also, server locales using "sudo locale-gen es_ES" won't actually install es_ES but es_ES.ISO88591 ("sudo locale-gen es_ES.utf8" will install es_ES.utf8)

Additionally, double check the string being used for setlocale(), it has to match EXACTLY the locale on the server. For example, setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES'); won't work on Ubuntu when running from a terminal "locale -a" shows "es_ES.utf8". setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8'); will now work.

Answer (score 4):

There is an outstanding five part tutorial at Sitepoint.com called **[Localizing PHP Applications “The Right Way”](http://www.sitepoint.com/localizing-php-applications-1/)**.  I highly recommend reviewing all five parts!

Answer (score 0):

I have created this xgettext command line for my project, it can be used by you as an example:

```
xgettext --files-from=source_files_list.txt --from-code=UTF-8 -L PHP -o mvap.po -d mvap -p languages --keyword=__:1 --keyword=_e:1 --keyword=_x:1,2c --keyword=_n:1,2 --keyword=_nx:1,2,4c --keyword=_n_noop:1,2 --keyword=_nx_noop:1,2,3c --keyword=_ex:1,2c --keyword=esc_html_e:1 --keyword=esc_html__:1
```

In this example the source_files_list.txt should be a text file containing the name of the files to be analyzed by xgettext separated by new lines.

the "--keyword=..." options are for recognizing the good functions used for translating strings (in this functions there are all wordpress translation functions I found)

it outputs "mvap.po" in the "./languages" folder with domain "mvap"