# Simple HTML site localization using with specific language routes

Tags: php, i18next

I want to translate a simple HTML site into two languages, I have always opted to duplicate the site and put each copy in a "language directory" as follows:

```
en/page.html
es/page.html
```

I feel the i18next library could be useful (for what I've read), but I would like to keep urls like in the previous case but with only one version of the file and I don't see a way to achieve this with such library.

Is this possible? Do I need to use node with express to achieve this? Or use a PHP solution?

Thanks for further answers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP solution is much more better than Javascript. For PHP multilanguage support check gettext, Below are few links which help you to understand

http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/

https://blog.udemy.com/php-gettext/

[complete example of gettext in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062832/complete-example-of-gettext-in-php)

http://blog.lingohub.com/2013/07/php-internationalization-with-gettext-tutorial/

Google Search: (php gettext tutorial)

Wordpress also use gettext libraries and tools for i18n.

http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers